# SharePoint Content Editor not displaying PnPJS Code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, pnp-powershell, pnp, pnp-js-core

I want to be able to display my PnPJS code and make it show up within the Content Editor, but I am having trouble pulling the data in and displaying it.

Here is what I have so far:

1.)

> I made a SharePoint list called O365RoadMap that automatically pulls new updates on Microsoft's Office 365 Roadmap and posts them
>   within the list using Microsoft Flow. 
>   [image]

2.)

```html
<div class="roadMap" id="roadMap"></div>

<script src="/siteassets/bootstrap3/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/PnP-JS-Core/pnp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/es6-Promise/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/fetch/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/CommonJS/CommonJS.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/knockout/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/knockout/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/publiccdnlib/dialog/open-sp-dialog.js"></script>
<!--END Scripts for O365-->

<script>

    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });
                                    <!--document.getElementById("roadMap").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)-->
    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.get().then(function(z){
        console.log(z);
        var result = z.results.map(a => ({
            Title: `${a.Title}`,
            Description: `${a.Description}`,
            Link: `${a.Link}`
            })
        )
        console.log(result);
    })
</script>
```

3.)

My Results are pulling in nicely using the Console log:
[image]

4.)
[image]
But for some reason, it's not displaying within the content editor and it's linked to the correct .txt file location, is there something that I am missing? All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the Custom Script feature via SharePoint admin center >
https://DOMAIN-admin.sharepoint.com/ > Settings >
https://DOMAIN-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx

> Custom Script > Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites >It takes about 24 hours for the change to take effect.

If the issue persists, follow the steps below to enable publishing feature :
A. Go to Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site Collection Features >

> https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site >
>   SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure > Activate. 
>   B. Go to Site Settings > https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx
>   Site Actions > Manage site features > SharePoint Server Publishing > Activate.

If you do not want to wait for 24 hours, then use this powershell command :

---

$adminUPN="USERID@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="DOMAIN"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Enter password"
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential

Set-SPOsite https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

---

please replace DOMAIN in URL with your domain, before clicking on link.